# Postgres on a Mac

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am trying to run Postgres on a mac OS 10.10.5.

I installed via Homebrew.  I had previously installed by just downloading from the web at some point but I want to use Homebrew across the board so I moved the original to the trash.

I run

```
brew services start postgres
```

That works fine.  I now see postgres in my activity monitor and can run

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP
```

to see

```
postgres   807  username    5u  IPv6 0x3ba11f77231b4ebb      0t0    TCP [::1]:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres   807  username    6u  IPv4 0x3ba11f772808980b      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)
```

I am trying to add a DB and some tables but when I run postgres I get

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

I removed the following line from my bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

I restarted the terminal and when I run which postgres I see it is pointing to

```
/usr/local/bin/postgres
```

I don't know how to interact with postgres or get the envoirment fixed up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `psql` is the name of the client. `postgres` is the server.

Comment: teppic is saying you need to run the command `psql` if you want to *"talk"* to the database and create tables or insert data - rather than the command `postgres` which starts it up.